# Can't import mRemote sessions into MobaXterm

Tags: mobaxterm, mremoteng

I have hundreds of devices saved in mRemoteNG and would very much like to export these and import them into MobaXterm. When I do this however it seems like only a few sessions out of the hundreds actually gets imported. Most folders are empty as you can see in this screenshot [After imported to MobaXterm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YuRV.png). I do this by clicking on Import sessions from third-party programs then MRemote. Can I not fully import mRemoteNG sessions into MobaXterm?

I did read this 'this is limited to the import of hosts without users/port/passwords/advanced settings' but the few sissions from mRemoteNG that did import does have port numbers in the settings. Any idea why the rest of the sessions aren't importing? Thanks.

I tried saving a new mRemoteNG export file and importing it MobaXterm. I thought it would import all saved sessions from mRemoteNG.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MobaXterm Home(free) or Professional version(paid)?

Free is limited to 12 sessions.
[MobaXTerm Free tier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8eOu.png)